# How to make one-row table using divs

Tags: html, css

There is a block with 100% width, its height changes according to content inside. I need to separate it to 2 parts: left and right. They should have 100% of main block's height and left blocks's width should be for example 30%, right - 70%. It's very easy to make it using table, because cells in one row have the same height and change it according to each other. But how to copy it using divs?

Comment: Do you want us to code it for you? Have you tried anything yet??

Comment: Have you tried `display:table` and `display:table-cell`?

Comment: I don't need code. Just a main idea like "use some float for something" or "use that position property" or something else

Comment: I'm going to try display:table, okay

Comment: I'm not particularly fond of display:table and display:table-cell, sometimes they work exactly as I need them to, other times, they just don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try to do this on your own first, but I can help you get started:

Css

```
.wrapper {width: 100%; float: left;}
.left {width:30%; float: left;}
.right {width: 70%; float: left;}

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">Left Content</div>
    <div class="right">Right Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code:

```
<div id="container" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="leftColumn" style="width: 30%; float: left;">left</div>
        <div class="rightColumn" style="width: 70% ;float:left;">right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: inline styles = baaaaaaaad